# paperclip error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, paperclip

i am trying paperclip for the first time and followed [this tutorial](http://jimneath.org/2008/04/17/paperclip-attaching-files-in-rails/)

all is well until i use **styles**. this is the code

```
has_attached_file :photo, :url => "/uploads/products/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",  
:path => ":rails_root/public/uploads/products/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
:styles => { :thumb=> "100x100#" }
```

the error i see on the console is

```
[paperclip] An error was received while processing: #<Paperclip::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError: C:/DOCUME~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/stream,2956,1.jpg is not recognized by the 'identify' command.>
```

what does this mean? I have no idea what it means. Should i install this **ImageMagick**?

I tried installing it as a plugin as per this [page](http://vantulder.net/rails/magick/). This also returns an error that "**plugin not found**".

what am i missing here?

**update:** I am on windows xp. webrick server. I have rmagick gem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run `identify` on your command prompt. If it identifies itself as ImageMagick, you have it installed. Next, get a jpg that you know opens in a viewer and try `identify <image>.jpg`. If it shows the image properties, you can be sure you have ImageMagick working properly. If not, depending on your OS, install IM again.

Sometimes, you might have to remove the preinstalled libjpeg and libpng libraries that come installed with your OS, for IM to install properly. Since you are on windows, you need not worry about this. Just follow the installation for windows from here: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/install-source.php and be sure to set the paths right.

Comment: is is necessary to install ImageMagick. How about using rmagick plugin?

Comment: rmagick uses ImageMagick to process images. rmagick is just a ruby wrapper for ImageMagick.

Comment: you are right.. it was a problem with my local machine's ImageMagick. The code works fine in my server.. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

in the source of paperclip.rb , 
if you change the line
option.split("'").map{|m| "'#{m}'" }.join("\'")
to the following:
option.split("'").map{|m| "\"#{m}\"" }.join("\'")

it works
Here is the complete changed method:

```
def quote_command_options(*options)
  options.map do |option|
    option.split("'").map{|m| "\"#{m}\"" }.join("\\'")
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

it means "identify" failed to tell what kind of file you uploaded, that might be caused by a bad file upload but also by a missing ImageMagick. I dont know how that is usually handled on windows.

Comment: it cannot be bad file upload as it works fine if don't mention styles. how do i know if ImageMagick is missing?

Comment: bad meaning "the content of your file is broken"

for details on paperclip on windows see http://thewebfellas.com/blog/2008/11/2/goodbye-attachment_fu-hello-paperclip

Comment: followed the link you mentioned. still no use. 
now i have installed RMagick and included a patch for temp-file.
the console is returning the same error

Answer (score 0):

You need install the ImageMagick

Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just installed imagemagick and you're on windows, it may help to do a "full reboot". I assume something wasn't stopping properly, and wasn't picking up the new path.

(probably just closing everything will work, but I just went for a full reboot to be sure)